# How can I get "pattern"attribute from component (html) to Controller (javascript)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, regular-expressions, javascript-controller

How can I get `"/ˆ[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/"` in the Controller class?

```
                        <label for="clientEmail">E-mail</label>
                        <lightning:input name="clientEmail"
                                         type="email"
                                         pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$" 
                                         aura:id="clientEmail"
                                         required="false" 
                                         value="{!v.clientEmail}"
                                         label="E-mail" 
                                         variant="label-hidden"
                                         maxlength="60" />
```

I tried:

```
let rgxEmail= "/ˆ" + cmp.find(clientEmail).get("v.pattern") +"/";
if (!(rgxEmail.test(valueEmail))) {
            let errorMsg = "Invalid email" + "\n";
 }
```

But it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/pattern/` is only for *literal* regular expressions in source code. Do not use `/pattern/` in the `pattern` attribute, nor when using the `test` method.

The pattern should be:

```
pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$"
```

And in your code:

```
let emailRegex = new RegExp(cmp.find(clientEmail).get('v.pattern'));
if(!emailRegex.test(valueEmail)) {
```

Note that String.prototype.test doesn't exist, which is why you're having a problem doing that, you should be constructing a new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object.

Also, it's not normally necessary to do that, you can use the built-in validation logic:

```
let emailInput = cmp.find(clientEmail);
if(!emailInput.checkValidity()) {
  emailInput.reportValidity();
}
```

This is outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm#!). Here's how they recommend checking all fields:

```
    var allValid = component.find('contact').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
        inputCmp.reportValidity();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
    }, true);

    if (allValid) {
      // continue, all fields are valid
    }
```